# How to fetch data which is not cached?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

When I try to interact with data an error is thrown.

```
const user = client.users.cache.get(user.id);
user.send(message);
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Explanation of cache utility**

Cache is a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection), an extend of [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) but with [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) methods and more. It's mainly used by [managers](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/search?query=manager) and used to prevents useless API calls, when data is fetched it will be cached too and you will be able to retrieve it how many time you want without sending API request. So when data is not cached it means that the data was not fetched yet and you'll need to.

A request is a call to the [Discord API](https://discord.com/developers/docs) which is done by the [Discord.js](https://discord.js.org/) module, to wait the response of the Discord server, the [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) need to be [awaited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) with `await` keyword or [`<Promise>.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method.

**Fetch example**

You can fetch data and assign the response in a variable, when you want to access it another time you will be able to retrieve data in the cache.

```
/* Data wasn't fetched so not cached yet */
console.log(client.users.cache.get(user.id)); // undefined

/* Request data from Discord */
const fetchedData = await client.users.fetch(user.id);
console.log(fetchedData); // User {}

/* Data has been fetched so you can retrieve data from cache */
console.log(client.users.cache.get(user.id)); // User {}
```

After these explanations, it's normal that this error appears since it's not possible to apply a method on something `undefined`.

> TypeError: Cannot read property '' of undefined