# When sending embeds, should the last line be channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] })?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm kind of stuck with this portion of the code. I'm currently coding a discord bot for a school project as well as personal use. The main purpose of the discord bot is to send embeds and casual commands where someone says "goodnight" and the bot will respond goodnight. For the goodnight part of the code, I have it pretty much written correctly, but how do I get it to respond by tagging the persons discord tag? such as instead of my current code being `else if (message.content === 'goodnight'){ message.channel.send('Goodnight!');` How would I get it to say "Goodnight @discordtag"

Secondly, the embed portion of the code is what I'm struggling with the most. I'm pretty much following the guides on https://discordjs.guide as well as some youtube videos, but I seem to not be able to find the answer. I'm getting the error "channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
^

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')

My code for the example embed is:

```
const channel = client.channels.cache.get('912186200910102559')
const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#5104DB')
        .setTitle("Boombap's Cookout Rules")
        .setAuthor({ name: 'Rules', iconURL: 'https://gridfiti.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Gridfiti_Blog_AnimeCars_NissanSilviaS13.jpg'})
        .addFields(
            { name: 'Rule 1', value: 'No racist, sexist or any type of hate speech towards other members.'},
            { name: 'Rule 2', value: 'No scamming.'},
            { name: 'Rule 3', value: 'No discussions of anything illegal, if you think it might be just do not mention it in the discord.'},
            { name: 'Rule 4', value: 'No advertisements of other services.'}

        )

channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fetch data which is not cached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70498618/how-to-fetch-data-which-is-not-cached)

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first part of your question, you can mention the user by `Goodnight ${message.author}` or `Goodnight <@${message.author.id}>` - both will return the same value (the discord mention).

`channel` is undefined, so that means there is no attribute `send()` as the error suggests. You can either fetch/cache a channel to send to a specific channel such as

```js
const channel = client.channels.cache.get('ID');
```

Or use the attribute `channel` on the `message` - `message.channel.send()`
[DJS Docs: Message: channel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=channel)

Comment: so I have ```const channel = client.channels.cache.get('ID');``` at the beginning section of my discord embed code but the probably is getting the code to execute after inputting node . in the terminal. In the last line I have ```message.channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });``` and it gives me an error saying message not defined.

Comment: So if you define channel at the top of the file, you can do `channel.send()`: based on the error message you provided in the question, it seems the ID isn't correct or you don't have the **`GUILDS`** intent - you need both in order to work

Answer (score -1):

What is channel defined as? Try replacing channel with `message.channel`

Comment: I'm new to coding so I'm sorry if I don't know what you mean! but I don't have the channel defined specifically, I'm following discordjs.guide and in the embed section it says in the last line to make it ```message.channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });``` whenever is use message.channel.send it says that message is not defined but when I use channel.send it says send isn't defined

Comment: @Jedi Can you show us more of your code