# Discord js role.members not return all members

Tags: heroku, discord.js

I have created a bot that allows, among other things, to send a message to those who belong to a certain role.
The bot is hosted on Heroku (free version, with a mandatory restart every day)
When I try to retrieve the members of the role in question I have the impression to retrieve only the members who are connected since the bot restart (or who have been online).
I have 27 members of a role but the bot retrieves only 3

[screenshot members discord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WR8om.png)

[data in debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFn5g.png)

Here is my code :

```
client.on("messageCreate", message =>{
  message.guild.roles.fetch(roleMembersId).then(role => {
   role.members.forEach(member => { 
      console.log("user "+ member.user.username)
      })
   })
})
```

I have the same behavior if I use interactions or directly the client

Is there a solution to this problem? I did not find anything like this when I searched

Comment: What intents have you enabled?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70498618/how-to-fetch-data-which-is-not-cached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you're missing the `GUILD_PRESENCES` intent.

For discord.js v14:

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences
  ]
})
```

For lower versions you can try and use:

```
const  Discord = require("discord.js");

const client = new Discord.Client({ 
  intents: [
    'GUILDS','GUILD_MESSAGES','GUILD_PRESENCES'
  ]
});
```

Comment: `GuildPresences` has nothing to do with this

Comment: Removing this intent reproduces the problem mentioned in the question.

Comment: I add the Intent Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES and enable PRESENCE INTENT on Discord Developer Portal. It's working, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

[`Role#members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Role?scrollTo=members) only returns *cached* members, as you can see in the description, and [source](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/main/packages/discord.js/src/structures/Role.js#L158). You can fetch all members (and cache them) first, before using it

```js
await message.guild.members.fetch()
const members = message.guild.roles.cache.get(roleId).members
members.forEach(m => console.log(`user ${m.user.username}`))
```

Comment: I tried this method but I got an "undefined guild" error. I tried the method of Crytek1012 that worked. I didn't look further but thanks for your help!